# Google Sheet filter execution by script on open

Tags: google-apps-script

I have google sheet with multiple data on it. I would like to filter one column on sheet open automatically. Please advise some script to execute it.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please show code example and where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi Peter, I do not have any code yet. I have one Google form which collects data. I want to filter it by Autofilter by script when I open the sheet to see data collected from form.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:Z");

 // Sorts by the values in column 2 (B)
 range.sort(2);
}
```

Comment: Hello Friend, I want filter the data Sort i tried but its not helping as I want to filter data on multiple column.

Answer (score 0):

I used filter formula on different sheet with input from another cell to filter.
Combination of data validation.

=iferror((if(F1=Choice!$B$80,(sort((FILTER('Form Responses 1'!A2:O,'Form Responses 1'!B2:B=D1,'Form Responses 1'!C2:C <> F1)),1,true)),(sort((FILTER('Form Responses 1'!A2:O,'Form Responses 1'!B2:B=D1,'Form Responses 1'!C2:C = F1)),1,true)))),"No Data / or wrong equipment selection combination")